# Download Airports from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, data, europe

Is there any way to download all airports in Europe from OSM?

What I'm looking for is the Airport perimeter, (lines or polygons, dosn't matter)

I know that I could download all Europe, and then filter by attributes, but what I ask is if is there any way for do it directly.

Some kind of 'where', where I can ask for download ONLY the data

```
where column Aeroway is not null
```

Comment: airport are points and polygon areas, this also includes model aircraft (Germany) locations. see http://ourairports.com/data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say check out WeoGeo's site:

http://market.weogeo.com/datasets/osm-openstreetmap-planet.html

You can draw a bounding box, select geometry types, and even filter by attributes.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [OverpassAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) because it is not that much data.

You can easily construct a statement that filters for [aeroway=aerodrome](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Airports) via http://overpass-turbo.eu

As always please be skeptical about the quality/coverage of OSM data and it's tagging.

Maybe it's worth to have a look at this page and parse the data (if open licensed): http://www.openflights.org